# Webservice PHP não funciona!

Tags: php, web-service, post, postman

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que utilizará um *webservice* em PHP e a estrutura que irá ser chamada para executar esse *webservice* é a seguinte:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8") ;

  require_once(  "Core.class.php" ) ;
  require_once( "Nomes.class.php" ) ;

    $acao = "";
    $core = new Core( ) ;
    $nome = new Nomes( $core ) ;

    if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
        $acao = $_POST['acao'];

        switch ($acao) {
            case "R":
            $lista = $nome->search( ) ;
            echo json_encode( $lista ) ;

                break;
        }
    }

?>
```

Estou testando no Postman colocando "acao" no parâmetro e "R" de valor, porém nada retorna. Antes de eu colocar o `if(isset($_POST['acao'])){$acao = $_POST['acao'];` que utilizarei para criar um CRUD, ele estava funcionando normalmente, somente após isso ele parou de dar resultados. Alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a pergunta aparentemente você não está enviando o header (do protocolo HTTP) content-type na requisição para seu webservice. É necessario que no postman você envie o header `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` para que as informações enviadas possam ser colocadas no super global `$_POST` (eventualmente você pode usar multipart/form-data). Basimente o header da requisição deve ter pelo menos isto:

```
POST /a.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

acao=R
```

Com este codigo modificado a partir do seu:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8") ;

  //require_once(  "Core.class.php" ) ;
  //require_once( "Nomes.class.php" ) ;

    $acao = "";
    //$core = new Core( ) ;
    //$nome = new Nomes( $core ) ;

    if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
        $acao = $_POST['acao'];

        switch ($acao) {
            case "R":
            $lista = ['alguma coisa'] ;
            echo json_encode( $lista ) ;

            break;
        }
    }

?>
```

Obtem-se como resposta:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

["alguma coisa"]
```